# How to close a tab in Spyder for Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, spyder

I had this little problem that made me crazy for a while, until I ran into the solution by chance, so even if it'is a trivial issue I want to share it.

Answer (score 8):

Just click on the left side of the *name of the file*, on its tab, in the tabs bar. It's like a hidden button.
 Check the picture
[image: the hidden area where to press]
Hope it will be useful to somebody

Comment: why not use the big red close button?

Comment: It was a pic from a Win OS spyder, now there's the correct one. Thank you